# jQuery: select first matching descendant with a specific class

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML structure:

```
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li class="item">two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li class="item">four</li>

        <li id="click"> CLICK ME </li>
    </ul>
```

When I click on #click, I want to change the background color of ONLY the first child of ul that has a class of .item

I am trying this, but its not working:

```
    $('#click').click(function(){
        $("ul").first('.item').css('background-color','red');
    });
```

Comment: `$('ul').find('.item').first()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First doesn't accept a selector, [as you can see in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/first/). Use `.find` or `.children` with `.first`:

```
$("ul").children('.item').first().css(...);
```

This will reduce the set of selected elements to the first selected element.

If you have multiple lists and want to target the first `li.item` element of each of them, you can use `.map`:

```
$("ul").map(function() {
    return $(this).children('.item').get(0);
}).css(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#click').click(function(){
    $("ul").children('.item').first().css('background-color','red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is
$("li.item").first().css('background-color','red');